# Access Query Combine Records from Many-to-Many into one row

Tags: sql, ms-access

This should be easy but I'm having a hard time.

I have a many-to-many relationship where, for example, many cars can have many components.

[image: Don't mind the relationships, this is a screenshot of a query, not the relationships]

So I want a query to return all cars and the subsequent components used. If no component is used it should just return a NULL value.

```
Car | Engine  | Tyre
----------------------
1   | Engine3 |
2   | Engine4 | Tyre3
3   | Engine1 | Tyre1
```

But with the following SQL:

```
SELECT Car.idCar, Engine.idEngine, Tyre.idTyre
FROM ((Component 
RIGHT JOIN (Car 
LEFT JOIN Car_Component ON Car.idCar = Car_Component.idCar) ON Component.idComponent = Car_Component.idComponent) 
LEFT JOIN Engine ON Component.idComponent = Engine.idComponent) 
LEFT JOIN Tyre ON Component.idComponent = Tyre.idComponent;
```

I get:

```
Car | Engine  | Tyre
----------------------
1   | Engine3 | 
2   | Engine4 | 
2   |         | Tyre3
3   | Engine1 | 
3   |         | Tyre1
```

I've been searching for a solution for quite some time now and I'm pretty sure I need to make subqueriesm but my knowledge of subqueries is limited and I don't know how to start.

[Here is the problem in SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7da22/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Does the following query work for you [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39972/1/0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Car.idCar, Engine.idEngine, Tyre.idTyre
FROM (((Car 
INNER JOIN Car_Component ON Car.idCar = Car_Component.idCar) 
INNER JOIN Component ON Car_Component.idComponent = Component.idComponent) 
LEFT JOIN Engine ON Component.idComponent = Engine.idComponent)
LEFT JOIN Tyre ON Component.idComponent = Tyre.idComponent;
```

Comment: This doesn't return any records whatsoever.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work?  I tested it using this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdbbd/1/0) and it returns what I expect it to.  Do you have some sample data I can test it on?

Comment: Nice, that SQL Fiddle. I tested my original query in there and it returned the same thing as your query. I definitely blame Access now.

Comment: I noticed you edited your answer, but the idComponent you're using are still not unique. Each component (eg Engine, Tyre) needs to have a unique idComponent. I edited your [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/501cd/1/0) slightly to represent the data correctly. Could you please have another look?